# Virtual function in an abstract type returning GObject pointer is not introspectible

Tags: gobject-introspection

I'm playing around with `libpeas` and I stumbled upon a problem with the way gobject-introspection works.

In `libpeas` there is a type called `PluginLoader` (see [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libpeas/-/blob/1679109644c4ce1aedbb5d6bcfa30116b594a794/libpeas/peas-plugin-loader.h#L60)).

There is a method called `create_extension` that returns `PeasExtension *` which is a point to a `GObject`. When I add this type to gobject-introspection and I check the resulting GIR file for this method I can see that it's marked as `introspectable="0"`:

```xml
<field name="create_extension" introspectable="0">
<callback name="create_extension" introspectable="0">
  <source-position filename="../libpeas/peas-plugin-loader.h"
                   line="60"/>
  <return-value>
    <type name="Extension" c:type="PeasExtension*"/>
  </return-value>
  <parameters>
    <parameter name="loader" transfer-ownership="none">
      <type name="PluginLoader" c:type="PeasPluginLoader*"/>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="info" transfer-ownership="none">
      <type name="PluginInfo" c:type="PeasPluginInfo*"/>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="ext_type" transfer-ownership="none">
      <type name="GType" c:type="GType"/>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="n_parameters" transfer-ownership="none">
      <type name="guint" c:type="guint"/>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="parameters" transfer-ownership="none">
      <type name="GObject.Parameter" c:type="GParameter*"/>
    </parameter>
  </parameters>
</callback>
</field>
```

When I change the return value to `void *` and recompile the `introspectable="0"` attribute is gone from the GIR file. If I change it to `GObject *` then the `introspectable="0"` attribute is still present.

It looks like it becomes non-introspectable when it returns an instance of GObject (a pointer). But I don't undestand why?

By reading the gobject introspection docs it looks like returning a GObject instance is a valid use case. Maybe it has something to do with that `PluginLoader` type is abstract and this is a virtual method?

Could any annotations help in making this object introspectable without changing the method signature?

Comment: “When I add this type to gobject-introspection” — how are you doing that?

From the sounds of your question, you are trying to create a GIR file for libpeas, but it [already exists](https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/libpeas-dev/filelist) as `Peas-1.0.gir`.

Looking at `Peas-1.0.gir`, `create_extension()` is not introspectable because it has a varargs argument, which is specific to C. The `create_extension_with_properties()` method is introspectable, and shadows `create_extension()`.

Comment: @PhilipWithnall you're looking at the `create_extension` from `PeasEngine` class and I'm talking about `create_extension` from `PluginLoader`. There is no `create_extension_with_properties` for `PluginLoader`. `PluginLoader` is not exported in the upstream version so I'm adding it by making this changed to the build scripts: https://gist.github.com/cmrd-senya/1f9595f6a52feeeb886c976f5b786a70

Comment: Ah, apologies. Look at the output from `g-ir-scanner` — since `--warn-all` is passed to it, it prints an error which indicates why `create_extension()` isn’t introspectable:
“../../source/libpeas/libpeas/peas-plugin-loader.h:91: Warning: Peas: peas_plugin_loader_create_extension: return value: Missing (transfer) annotation”

Comment: Okay! I understand it now! I thought that in could be related to missing annotations but I didn't notice the message. I tried putting annotations at `create_extension` in `_PeasPluginLoaderClass` but actually I had to put the annotations at `peas_plugin_loader_create_extension` that is defined below. I tried that and it worked!
Thanks @PhilipWithnall! Do you want to write an answer here?

Comment: I’m not that fussed about writing an answer. Feel free to write up your experience yourself though :)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Philip in the comments I've managed to resolve the issue.

There was actually a message in the output of `g-ir-scanner` saying:

```
../../source/libpeas/libpeas/peas-plugin-loader.h:91: Warning: Peas: peas_plugin_loader_create_extension: return value: Missing (transfer) annotation
```

By this message I understood that to make the virtual function `create_extension` introspectible I have to add annotations, but not at the function pointer in the `PeasPluginLoaderClass` definition, but rather next to accessor function `peas_plugin_loader_create_extension`.